# Non-english(Urdu) text not shown in Recycler View properly

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, unicode

For my project I have created an API that sends JSON data to an Android app. The JSON data has some non-english text ie. Urdu characters. When calling the API from browser or Postman I get the proper API but on Android app the non-English characters does not show properly rather I get strange characters.
Following is the JSON result from Postman

```
{
    "pdfsubjects": {
        "0": {
            "id": "1",
            "course_title": "اردو",
            "books": "2555",
            "icon": "https://oer.uoch.edu.pk/public/contents/img/groups/language_litrature.jpg",
            "type": "University"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": "8",
            "course_title": "English",
            "books": "578",
            "icon": "/img/groups/language_litrature.jpg",
            "type": "University"
        }
    }
}
```

Attached is the screenshot of the android app showing the issue.
[strange characters for non-englsih text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEMyL.png)

Please see how can I fix this issue.

Thanks